# span tag inside img tag with Helper Html->image and Html->tag in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'd like to generate the following html code  with Htmlhelper

```
<a class="menu" href="/lib/movies/view/6">
          <span>Movie</span>
    <img src="img/icons/movie.png" alt="Movie">
</a>
```

I've used this code but it does not work

```
echo $this->Html->image("../img/icons/movie.png",
              array("alt" => "Movie",
              "url" => array("controller" => "movies", "action" => "view", 6),
              "class" => "menu",
              $this->Html->tag("span","movie")
              ));  
?>
```

it generates the following code

```
<a href="/lib/movies/view/6"><img src="/contest2/img/../img/icons/movie.png" alt="Movie" class="tile" <span>Movie</span>="<span>Movie</span>" /></a>
```

You can see that the src is not correct  neither the span tag

When I write the php code without $this->tag  it works but of course it does not create the span tag.

Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
 echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('span', 'Movie') . $this->Html->image('../img/icons/movie.png', array('alt' => 'Movie')), array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'view', 6), array('class' => 'menu', 'escape' => false));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in the code in the question.

### Appropriate use of the image function

The path to image is not relative to the current request, to generate an image use either a relative path to the img folder:

```
$this->Html->image("icons/movie.png");
// output <img src="/contest2/img/icons/movie.png" ...
                    ^............^ CakePHP added this automatically
```

Or an absolute url (absolute to the application install):

```
$this->Html->image("/img/icons/movie.png");
// output <img src="/contest2/img/icons/movie.png" ...
                    ^........^ CakePHP added this automatically (the application root url)
```

### Use `Html->link`

The main problem with the code in the question is trying to overload the `image` function with too much code - the `image` function has a url option for defining simple images inside a link, for anything more split things up:

```
$image = $this->Html->image(...);
echo $this->Html->link($image, $url, array('escape' => false));
```

In this case that means:

```
$image = $this->Html->image("icons/movie.png", array('alt' => 'Movie'));
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<span>Movie</span>' . $image, 
    $url, 
    array('class' => 'menu', 'escape' => false)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I've used the second response because it includes the link to the controller.